# How to query from two elasticsearch indexes with one query

Tags: elasticsearch

Newbie here. I have two indexes: /items and /categories that contain data similar to this:

```
#Items:
{ id:1, name: "banana", categories: [1] },
{ id:2, name: "coconut", categories: [1] },
{ id:3, name: "smoothie", categories: [1, 2] }

#Categories
{ id:1, name: "Apple" },
{ id:2, name: "Banana" }
```

I want to create a query with **bana** as a query string and I should return items 1 and 3. It should not return category objects. ID 1 because of the name match and ID 3 because it has a category that has a name match.

How could a query like this be constructed?

My current query does not return item `3` and simply like

```
GET /items/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "query_string":{
          "query":"bana"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to create two indexes for this? maybe use `name` directly in **Item** index to replace id:

```
{ id:1, name: "banana", categories: ["Apple"] }
```

Since **index** will have its own dictionary, will not cause extra disk space.

if really need to join two indexes, maybe you want to try [Parent-Child Relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html), but it will **deprecated** in future, and replaced by: [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html), this way also will keep data in one index.